# Custom Button to fill a specific Picklist Value

Tags: custom-button

I am familiar with creating a custom button to 'carry' a value over from object to object, but I am unsure if it is possible to fill a Picklist Field with a specific choice.

Here's the existing link, and I need to prefill Chance__c with the pickval 10% when creating a new custom object record from the Account view related list button.

```
https://na2.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?
ent=01I40000000IBaw&save_new_url=%2Fa01%2Fe%3FCF00N400000029JnV_lkid={!Account.Id}
&CF00N400000029JoT={!Account.Additional_Owner__c}
&CF00N400000029JoT_lkid={!Account.Additional_OwnerId__c}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have no problems with that. Maybe if you'd show us what fails to work?

I've quickly created a new picklist on Contact in my dev. edition. The field got assigned Id `00N70000003FLpI` (not really important) and the values I've put in the picklist are `10%`, `20%`, ... `100%`.

Anyway - it works like a charm if I'll append `&00N70000003FLpI=30%25` to the URL that shows when I click "new Contact" on the related list. `30%25` because `%25` is url-encoded `%` sign and in reality you should be using either server-side `{!URLENCODE(...)}` or javascript's `encodeURI()` function, depending how you construct your link.

One thing to note is that `30%` must be an available picklist value. Any typos = problem. Any "limited set of values because of record type or dependent picklist" = problem. And by problem I mean that your value will be ignored, you'll get "None" or whatever was the default picklist value selected.

Looks like you want to "pass-through" the picklist value to be preset after the record type selection screen. In that case you might have to encode whole "prepopulate these fields plz" expression again. Check [URL Hack: Pass additional parameters into the saveURL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/url-hack-pass-additional-parameters-into-the-saveurl) for more ;)